# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter Orderid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When calling the Data action of the CheckoutController, I keep getting the following error:

[image: enter link description here]
I am using this technique for passing parameters in several other controllers and I haven't had any troubles there. My code of the CheckoutController and default route is shown below. Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.Functions;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class CheckoutController : Controller
    {
        private thelearningbayEntities _db = new thelearningbayEntities();
        private Auth Permission = new Auth();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Data(int Orderid) 
        {
            if (Permission.Check(0))
            {
                var email = Session["email"].ToString();
                _db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; 

                var result = (from order_line in _db.order_line
                              join orders in _db.orders on order_line.id_order equals orders.id_order
                              join product in _db.product on order_line.p_id equals product.p_id
                              where (orders.email == email) && (orders.id_order == Orderid)

                              select new { order_line.amount, product.p_name, product.price, product.t_image}).ToList();

                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            Session["referrer"] = "/Checkout/";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");

        }
    }
}
```

Routeconfig:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Product",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "MainPage", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your action method parameter to `Id` so that your request url matches the default routing pattern, which is `{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

```
public ActionResult Data(int id) 
{
      //use id
}
```

**Or**

Fix the code which generates the link to this action method to use the `orderId` routeValue(querystring key) explicitly.

For example, If you are using the `Html.ActionLink` method,

```
@Html.ActionLink("Checkout","Data","Checkout",new { orderId=20 },null)
```

Or the markup (the helper ultimately generate the markup like below)

```
<a href="/Checkout/Data?orderId=20">Checkout</a>
```